# CSS - background-size not changing

Tags: html, jquery, css, background-size

I am trying to change the background width/height of these div elements but `background-size: 1px 1px;` doesn't even seem to be working. I am trying to achieve something like this, with "Cutter O.D." and "Min. Cutter Travel" having a small white background overlaying the measurement lines no matter the size of the other divs.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Kaevonz/fkbrpL54/37/

[image]

For the Cutter O.D. text label, I am using `left: 15%;` and `right: 15%`, but for larger inputs such as (50, 60, 2), there is too large of a gap as shown below due to the background size changing.

[image]

For the "Min. Cutter Travel" text label, when I add a background to it, the background is too big and cuts off the measurement lines. I am unable to use `background-size` either.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(function() {

    $('.div3 span').hide();
    $('.div5').hide();
    $('.div5brother').hide();
    $('.div1brother').hide();

    function hideObjects($) {
      $('.div1').hide();
      $('.div2').hide();
      $('.div3').hide();
      $('.div5brother').hide();
      $('.div1brother').hide();
    }

    function hideErrors($) {
      $('#error').hide();
      $('#error2').hide();
      $('#error3').hide();
      $('#error4').hide();
      $('#error5').hide();
    }
    
    function errorStatements($){
    
    }

    $(document).on('change', '#field_2w269, #field_wg4s2, #field_d6hwp', function() {
      mainCode()
    })

    function mainCode() {

      //Declare Variables for User Inputs
      const $outer_diameter = parseFloat($("#field_wg4s2").val());
      const $wall_thickness = parseFloat($("#field_d6hwp").val());
      const $cutter_diameter = parseFloat($("#field_2w269").val());
      //Convert diameters to radii
      const $cutter_radius = ($cutter_diameter / 2);
      const $pipeOutsideRadius = ($outer_diameter / 2);
      const $pipeInsideRadius = ($pipeOutsideRadius - $wall_thickness);
      //Find Cutter Travel
      const $cutterTravel = ($pipeOutsideRadius - (Math.sqrt(Math.pow($pipeInsideRadius, 2) - Math.pow($cutter_radius, 2))));
      //Convert sizes for Visual Representation
      //const $multiplier = 7.5; //pixel sizing multiplier for user inputs
      const $multiplier = (750 / ($cutterTravel + $outer_diameter)); //pixel sizing multiplier for user inputs
      const $visualPipeOD = ($outer_diameter * $multiplier);
      const $visualWallThk = ($wall_thickness * $multiplier);
      const $visualPipeID = ($visualPipeOD - (2 * $visualWallThk));
      const $visualCutDia = ($cutter_diameter * $multiplier);
      const $visualCutTravel = ($cutterTravel * $multiplier);

      if ($cutter_diameter > $outer_diameter) {
        $('#error').text('Cutter cannot be larger than Pipe O.D.').show();
        hideObjects($);
        return false;
      }

      if ($cutter_diameter > ($outer_diameter - (2 * $wall_thickness))) {
        $('#error2').text('Cutter cannot be larger than Pipe I.D.').show();
        hideObjects($);
        return false;
      }

      if ($cutter_diameter < 0) {
        $('#error').text('Please input a positive value').show();
        hideObjects($);
        return false;
      }

      if ($wall_thickness >= 0.33 * $outer_diameter) {
        $('#error4').text('Wall Thickness is invalid').show();
        hideObjects($);
        return false;
      }
      $('#error4').hide();


      if ($wall_thickness < 0) {
        $('#error3').text('Please input a positive value').show();
        hideObjects($);
        return false;
      }

      if ($outer_diameter < 0) {
        $('#error').text('Please input a positive value').show();
        hideObjects($);
        return false;
      }
      if ($cutter_diameter > 72) {
        $('#error').text('Cutter is too big.').show();
        hideObjects($);
        return false;
      }

      if ($outer_diameter > 100) {
        $("#error").text($outer_diameter + " is too big").show();
        hideObjects($);
        return false;
      }

      $('.div1').css({
        height: ($visualCutTravel),
        width: ($visualCutDia)
      });
      $('.div1').fadeIn(300);

      $('.div1brother').css({
        width: ($visualCutDia)
      });
      $('.div1brother').fadeIn(300);

      $('.div2').css({
        height: ($visualPipeOD),
        width: ($visualPipeOD),

      });
      $('.div2').fadeIn(300);

      $('.div3').css({
        height: ($visualPipeID),
        width: ($visualPipeID),

      });
      $('.div3').fadeIn(300);

      $('.div5').css({
        height: ($visualCutTravel),
        width: ($visualCutDia)
      });

      $('.div5brother').css({
        height: ($visualCutTravel),
        right: (99.5 - $visualCutDia / 2 - 80),
      });

      $('.div5brother > span').css({
        lineHeight: `${$visualCutTravel}px`,
      });
      $('.div5brother').fadeIn(300);

      /*$('.div1brother > span').css({
        right: (99.5 - $visualCutDia / 2 - 80),
        left: (99.5 - $visualCutDia / 2 - 80),
      });*/

      hideErrors($);
    }

    $(document).on('change', '#field_2w269', function() {
      $('.div1 span').fadeIn(100);
    })

    $(document).on('change', '#field_wg4s2', function() {
      $('.div3 span').fadeIn(100);
    })

    $(document).on('change', '#field_2w269', function() {
      $('.div5').fadeIn(100);
    })

  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.elem {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Cutter O.D. Visual */
.div1 {
  border-top: 3px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-left: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-right: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  height: 0px;
  background: white;
}

/* Cutter O.D. Measurement Label */
.div1brother {
  position: relative;
  width: 172.5px;
  height: 25px;
  border-left: 0.01px solid black;
  border-right: 0.01px solid black;
  border-top: 0.01px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

/* Cutter O.D. Text */
.div1brother span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  right: 15%;
  top: -3px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding-left: 0px;
  font-size: 9px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Pipe O.D. Visual */
.div2 {
  border: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

/* Pipe I.D. Visual */
.div3 {
  border: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Pipe O.D. Text */
.div3 > span {
  transform: translate(-10%, -55%) rotate(-10deg);
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Pipe O.D. Label */
.div4 {
  border-top: 0.5px dashed black;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-10deg);
}

/* Min. Cutter Travel Label */
.div5 {
  border: 0.5px dashed black;
  width: 120px;
  height: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
}

/* Min. Cutter Travel Measurement Label */
.div5brother {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -80px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 0.5px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid black;
  border-right: 0.5px solid black;
}

/* Min. Cutter Travel Measurement Label Text */
.div5brother > span {
  font-size: 9px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.div5container {
  width: 205px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<div class="container">
  <p id="error"></p>
  <p id="error2"></p>
  <p id="error3"></p>
  <p id="error4"></p>
  <p id="error5"></p>

  <div class="div1brother">
    <span>Cutter O.D.</span>
  </div>

  <div class="elem div1"></div>
  <div class="elem div2">
    <div class="elem div3"><span>Pipe O.D.</span>

      <div class="div5container">
        <div class="elem div5">
        </div>
        <div class="elem div5brother">
          <span>Min. Cutter Travel</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="elem div4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="number" id="field_2w269" placeholder="Enter Cutter O.D."> <br>
<input type="number" id="field_wg4s2" placeholder="Enter Outer Diameter"> <br>
<input type="number" id="field_d6hwp" placeholder="Enter Thickness"> <br>
<input type="button" id="bttn" name="calculate" value="Calculate">
</body>
```

Comment: It's not that some data sets work and some don't work, it's just that the smaller the values, the smaller the white gap is between the text and the left and right sides for Cutter O.D, this the better the measurement label look visually. For example, (3, 20, 2) looks very good, but (52, 60, 1) doesn't look good.